# The projection of the Newton law for a ball moving in an italic direction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

if I want to push the bowling ball in a direction which is not parallel to the lane, then I need to make a Projection on the axes (the x axis is parallel with the width of the lane and the y axis is parallel with the length of the lane) ... using the Newton's laws of motion
$\sum \vec F = m \vec a$ ,when I projected the force(which is the friction force) and the acceleration I got this:

$$\ -F_x   \cos(\theta) = m\cdot a_x\cdot \cos(\theta)\quad \text{ and }\ -F_y\cdot \sin(\theta) = m\cdot a_y\cdot  \sin(\theta)$$

by canceling out what is similar it gave me the same relation if the ball was moving forward with no angle

$$\ -F_x  = m\cdot  a_x \quad \text{and} \quad \ -F_y = m\cdot  a_y$$

why did I get that ?

Comment: Where did those negative signs come from?

Comment: $F_x=F\cos\theta$ is *already* the $x$-component, etc. It doesn’t need to be multiplied by another $\cos\theta$.

Comment: Your last two equations don't say the ball is moving forward without any angle, that would only be true if $a_x$ was $0$.

Comment: @G.Smith I put the negative sign because the force is the friction force and when I projected it, it was in the opposite direction comparing to the axes direction,

Comment: @G.Smith , oh I thought $ F_x $ is just a symbol

Comment: @AkshatSharma why? if I had a forward moving with an acceleration without any angle, the force will be $0$ on the y axis but it will be the same relation $−F_x=m.a_x$ on the x axis, right?

Comment: Yes in case of no angle the last equation would be equal to $0$ but in general with non zero angle the equations would be the same as the last two you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ doubled.

Start by simply ackowledging that you need the force component along the x-axis without plugging anything in yet:

$$F_x = ma_x.$$

Next, with $a_x$ being the wanted unknown and $F_x$ being a needed unknown, find an expression for $F_x$. Such an expression might be set up trigonometrically as $\cos(\theta)=\frac{F_x}{F}$:

$$F\cos(\theta) = ma_x.$$

Note how this includes $F$ and not $F_x$. And we here only have one cosine term. From this you can easily solve for $a_x$.

Same approach along the y-axis and then you find $a_y$, finalising you acceleration vector.

Comment: I think I understood, so if I want to find the a and I have the value of F I use $Fcos(θ)=ma_x$ and the same for y axis, and if I want to find the F and I have the value of a I use $F_x=macos(θ)$ and the same for y axis, is that right?

Comment: @RamaRanneh Yes, that is correct. Whether to use sine or cosine depends on the exact setup. You ought to draw out an imagined right-angled triangle every time to be sure which to use. When you know that, then you can set up the equations as you've outlined in the comment.